# Lazy evaluation of expression in Elixir

Tags: clojure, elixir, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to figure out if there is a macro similar to `delay` in clojure to get a lazy expression/ variable that can be evaluated later.

The use case is a default value for `Map.get/3`, since the default value comes from a database call, I'd prefer it to be called only when it's needed.

Comment: Looking at the source for "delay" in Clojure (here: https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/201a0dd9701e1a0ee3998431241388eb4a854ebf/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Delay.java) it looks like delay is closer to a protocol than a macro.  If I were you, I'd investigate protocols in Elixir and proceed in that fashion.

Comment: I checked `delay` source before asking the question, and it's interesting that `delay` was implemented in java rather than clojure - which allows for much different construct and manipulation of expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elixir's macro could be used for writing simple wrapper function for conditional evaluation. I've put one gist in the following, though it may be better/smarter way.

https://gist.github.com/parroty/98a68f2e8a735434bd60

Comment: This is the solution I ended up with as well, although my code was using if else, and looks much less nice.

It seems like there is no better way unless we actually got compiler support :-)


And one drawback comparing to `delay` in clojure is that we have to write a macro for every function we want to use, rather than having one universal operator.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be using processes. For example the map could be wrapped in a process like a GenServer or an [Agent](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Agent.html) where the default value will be evaluated lazy.

Comment: I don't quite follow how you could use a process for lazy eval, do you mind putting up some code as example?

Answer (score 1):

The default value can be a function which makes the expensive call. If `Map.get/3` isn't being used to return functions you can check if the value is a function and invoke it if it is returned. Like so:

```
def default_value()
  expensive_db_call()
end

def get_something(dict, key) do
  case Map.get(dict, key, default_value) do
    value when is_fun(value) ->
      value.() # invoke the default function and return the result of the call
    value ->
      value # key must have existed, return value
  end
end
```

Of course if the map contains functions this type of solution probably won't work.

Also check Elixir's Stream module. While I don't know that it would help solve your particular problem it does allow for lazy evaluation. From the documentation:

> Streams are composable, lazy enumerables. Any enumerable that generates items one by one during enumeration is called a stream. For example, Elixir’s Range is a stream:

More information is available in [the Stream documentation](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html).

Comment: Stream is not what I was looking for, I was looking for a way to delay any arbitrary expression.


Your solution with `case` is pretty close to the actual solution, but the solution would need to use macro to work with any arbitrary expression.

Answer (score 1):

"Generic" laziness is a bit of a tough nut to crack because it's a fairly broad question.  Streams allow laziness for enumerables but I'm not sure what laziness for an expression would mean.  For example what would a lazy form of `x = 1 + 2` be?  When would it be evaluated?

The thought that comes to mind for a lazy form of an expression is a procedure expression:

```
def x, do: 1 + 2
```

Because the value of x wouldn't be calculated until the expression is actually invoked (as far as I know).  I'm sure others will correct me if I'm wrong on that point. But I don't think that's what you want.

Maybe you want to rephrase your question--leaving out streams and lazy evaluation of enumerated values.

Answer (score 1):

`Map.get_lazy` and `Keyword.get_lazy` hold off on generating the default until needed, links the documentation below

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#get_lazy/3

https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Keyword.html#get_lazy/3

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in an anonymous function, then it will be evaluated when the function is called:

```
iex()> lazy = fn -> :os.list_env_vars() end
#Function<45.79398840/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>
iex()> lazy.()
```